# Best way to ensure a principal information is not edited with javascript

Tags: javascript, java, security, serialization, web-applications

I have a react app and an api that send all the links the user has access to.

From them, it creates all the menu.

I might still need the ROLE of my Principal client side to choose to display or not some information.

I was thinking to create a checksum of my Principal Object in java and send it with the principal object serialized to the react client.

I need to be able to evaluate the checksum from the client using javascript so user cannot use modified principal information (and modified ROLE).

What is the appropriate way to do so?

Comment: Please note that JavaScript is not Java.

Comment: Yes but it already exists, so do not reinvent the wheel (see signed tokens)

Comment: @evolutionxbox, My backend is a spring boot app in java and my client is a react application in javascript

Comment: @Arnaud Denoyelle, I have a oauth2 bearer token and I can add information like username to it. I also need the role on the client, if the user add a new role to it's list I need to provide a way to verify the token client side if it is your idea

Comment: @BigDong No, you don't but it is not an issue. The token must be signed on  server side with an algorithm that uses a private key known by the server alone.  The user can then modify information on client side (you cannot prevent it) but he/whe will not be able to produce a valid signature. Hence, you can detect on server side that the token is corrupted.

Comment: @BigDong You might want to take a look at https://jwt.io/

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle oauth2 use jwt, as I told you I already store a jwt. I think you missunderstand the request. I need a way to validate the jwt client side.

Comment: @BigDong I understand. Unfortunately, there is no bulletproof way of doing this because the user has access to the javascript code. Even if you implement an uncrackable check, the user still has the option to bypass it...
IMHO, the best you can do is either obfuscation or check user's roles before rendering HTML on server side.
Depending on your need, it might not be problematic if the user can access a restricted part of your app provided that the user cannot access restricted data.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle that's why I had this over idea, which is quit basic and work well: The server serialize a json object, attach its checksum to the serialization as a key. Client side, I just need to do a checksum and validate the entities are the same, if the user change the save model, I will be able to validate the model with a checksum. I know it seems a bit odd if the client can create it's own checksum, but it's better than nothing